# Brute-Force Substring Search Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, substring, brute-force

I'm trying to make a simple substring search using the brute force technique but I'm getting an error. I'm quite new to programming so please keep that in mind.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Csharp_Training
{
    
    class Program
    {
        public static int Search(string Text, string Pattern,int N, int M)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N - M; i++)
            {
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                {
                    if (Text[i + j] != Pattern[i])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (j == M) return i;
                }
            }
            return N;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Txt = "this is a test";
            string Pttrn = "test";
            int LN = Txt.Length;
            int LM = Pttrn.Length;
            int result = Search(Txt, Pttrn, LN, LM);
            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }          
}
```

Comment: Try use SubString method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < M; ...  if (j == M)` , the if condition will never be true, because `j<M`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple substring search (brute force)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632874/simple-substring-search-brute-force)

Comment: The `if (j == M)` line needs to be after the loop. Inside the loop, the condition will never be true. After the loop, it will be true if the pattern matched the text.

Comment: Also note that the condition `i < N - M` should be `i <= N - M`. Otherwise, you won't find the pattern when it's at the end of the text. For example text="abc" N=3, and pattern="bc" M=2. `i < N - M` means `i < 1` which will only check the pattern against index 0, when in fact the pattern will match at index 1.

Comment: You also need in the line `if (Text[i + j] != Pattern[i])`, to write "Pattern[**j**]" instead of "Pattern[**i**]". That's because `i` runs over your text, and `j` runs over your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues to be addressed to make it work properly.

```
public static int Search(string Text, string Pattern, int N, int M)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) // Not i < N - M
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            if (Text[i + j] != Pattern[j]) // Not Pattern[i]
            {
                break;
            }
            //if (j == M) return i;
        }
        if (j == M) return i; // Moved outside the inner loop
    }
    return -1; // Not return N
}
```